# Splitting values on the basis of count column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 2 columns

```
>mydata <- data.frame(Obj = c(1,2,3,2), Count = c(2,3,1,4))
>mydata
  Obj Count
1   1     2
2   2     3
3   3     1
4   2     4
```

I want to split the Obj column based on count to get the atomic objects like 
(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2)
Yeah that is reverse of the **table** function. Is there any function for doing this in R?

P.S: A simple for loop can do the trick, but I feel it is always good to use inbuilt efficient functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
rep(mydata$Obj,mydata$Count)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `rep`, with `Count` being the times argument

```
with(mydata, rep(Obj, Count))
```

or `rep.int`, which is a slightly faster implementation of `rep(x, times)`

```
with(mydata, rep.int(Obj,  Count))
```